# Exctract comments

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the new Excel feature to extract the new comments from a WorkSheet. I wrote the macro and it works properly. Nevertheless, one of my collegues wrote several comments in the same Cell. The code only reach the first one, before jump to other cell. Any guest of how extracting all the comment cell info?

I appreciate any help.

The used code is:

```
Sub extcommExcel()
    Dim xComm As CommentThreaded
    Dim AComm As CommentsThreaded
    Dim Oreply As CommentThreaded
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim ver As Integer
    
    ver = 0
    
    For Each sht In Application.Sheets    
        If sht.Name = "Comments" Then            
            ver = 1        
        End If        
    Next
    
    If ver = 0 Then        
        Set sht = Worksheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)
        sht.Name = "Comments"        
    Else    
        Set sht = Worksheets("Comments")    
    End If
        
    sht.Range("A1").Value = "Comment In"
    sht.Range("B1").Value = "Comment By"
    sht.Range("C1").Value = "Sheet"
    sht.Range("D1").Value = "Comments"
    
    With sht.Range("A1:D1")    
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Columns.ColumnWidth = 20    
    End With
       
    For Each sht In Worksheets       
        sht.Activate        
        Set AComm = ActiveSheet.CommentsThreaded
        
        For Each xComm In AComm               
            If sht.Range("A2") = "" Then    
                Sheets("Comments").Range("A2").Value = xComm.Parent.Address
                Sheets("Comments").Range("B2").Value = xComm.Author.Name
                Sheets("Comments").Range("C2").Value = sht.Name
                Sheets("Comments").Range("D2").Value = xComm.Text
            Else            
                Sheets("Comments").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = xComm.Parent.Address
                Sheets("Comments").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = xComm.Author.Name
                Sheets("Comments").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = sht.Name
                Sheets("Comments").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = xComm.Text            
            End If        
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The comments inserted looks like:

[image: Several comments in a cell]

Comment: Have you tried CommentThreaded.Replies?

Comment: Thanks selvarajmas for the guess. It works very fine.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by selvarajmas, I included the reference to replies and it work ok.

I share the final code (I am not an expert coding, so I am sure it can be improved:

```
Sub extcommExcel()

Dim xComm As CommentThreaded
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim xsht As Worksheet
Dim ver As Integer
Dim xRep As CommentThreaded

ver = 0

For Each sht In Application.Sheets

    If sht.Name = "Comments" Then
        
        ver = 1
    
    End If
    
Next

If ver = 0 Then
    
    Set sht = Worksheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)
    sht.Name = "Comments"
    
Else

    Set sht = Worksheets("Comments")

End If
    
sht.Range("A1").Value = "Comment In"
sht.Range("B1").Value = "Comment By"
sht.Range("C1").Value = "Sheet"
sht.Range("D1").Value = "Comments"

With sht.Range("A1:D1")

    .Font.Bold = True
    .Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
    .Columns.ColumnWidth = 20

End With

With sht

    For Each xsht In Worksheets
   
        For Each xComm In xsht.CommentsThreaded
    
            If sht.Range("A2") = "" Then

                .Range("A2").Value = xComm.Parent.Address
                .Range("B2").Value = xComm.Author.Name
                .Range("C2").Value = sht.Name
                .Range("D2").Value = xComm.Text
        
            Else
        
                .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = xComm.Parent.Address
                .Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = xComm.Author.Name
                .Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = sht.Name
                .Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = xComm.Text
        
            End If
    
            For Each xRep In xComm.Replies
            
                .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = xComm.Parent.Address & " - Reply"
                .Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = xRep.Author.Name
                .Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = sht.Name
                .Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = xRep.Text
            
            Next
        
        Next

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

As some times I need to export the comments in Word, I code also the following:

```
Sub extcommWord()

Dim xComm As CommentThreaded
Dim wApp As Object
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim xRep As CommentThreaded

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wApp.Visible = True
wApp.Documents.Add DocumentType:=0

For Each sht In Application.Sheets

    sht.Activate
    
    wApp.Selection.typetext sht.Name
    
    For Each xComm In sht.CommentsThreaded
    
        wApp.Selection.typetext "Cell" & xComm.Parent.Address & vbTab & " - Comment Author " & xComm.Author.Name
        wApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        wApp.Selection.typetext "Comment: " & xComm.Text
        
        wApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        wApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        
        For Each xRep In xComm.Replies
        
            wApp.Selection.typetext xComm.Parent.Address & " - Reply" & " - Reply Author " & xRep.Author.Name
            wApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
            wApp.Selection.typetext "Reply: " & xRep.Text
            wApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
            
            wApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
            wApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        
        Next
        
    Next

Next

Set wApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Regards,